# Problems at taking the Complex Derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $f(x+iy)=1/2\log(x^2+y^2)+i\arctan(y/x);x\ne 0,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is to be tested for complex differentiability. I am already stuck at the beginning.

It would be confortable to be able to write $f$ as $f(z)$, so I can formulate the CR-DGLs by using the Wirtinger derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}$. Furthermore, I could calculate $f'(z)$ more easily (if existent). I can already tell that $\mathfrak{R}(z)$ must not be zero. I kind of want to avoid doing $\mathbb{C}\simeq\mathbb{R}^2$, e.g. using the CR-DGLs in the coordinate form.

Comment: If the function $f$ was given to you in this form, my guess is that you are supposed to check Cauchy-Riemann. Anyway, computing the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts is not so difficult, so I fail to see why you want to dodge this task... (Of course, $f(z)=\mathrm{Log}(z)+c$ for some constant depending on the connected domain $z$ is in, from which holomorphy follows, but this is beside the point of the exercise.)

Comment: Ok, seems computing in coordinate form was not bad at all.

Comment: When you write \mathrm{log} and \mathrm{arctan} rather than \log and \arctan, then you don't get proper spacing in things like $3\log 5$ or $3\log(5):$ $$ \begin{align} \text{3\log5} & \qquad 3\log5 \\  \text{3\mathrm{log}5} & \qquad 3\mathrm{log}5 \\  \text{3\log(5)} & \qquad 3\log(5) \\  \text{3\mathrm{log}(5)} & \qquad 3\mathrm{log}(5) \end{align} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u & = \frac 1 2 \log(x^2+y^2) \\[10pt]
v & = \arctan \frac y x \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & = \frac x {x^2+y^2} \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & = \frac 1 {1 + \left( y/x \right)^2} \cdot \frac 1 x = \frac x {x^2 + y^2} \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & = \cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & = \cdots\cdots
\end{align}
Check to see whether the Cauchy–Riemann equations are satisfied.